# Windows phone runtime make live tile with a chart inside

Tags: graph, charts, windows-runtime, live-tile

I am making a windows phone app that supports live tiles. Is there a library that can generate charts?

[image: A example of what it would look like]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but... [winrtxamltoolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). Use the library to generate the charts in a usercontrol and then rendertargetbitmap to generate the image to update your Tile.